# How to mock querydsl query?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito, querydsl

In my prod code I have the following queryDsl query:

```
Collection<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("blue");
myList.add("green");
myList.add("yellow");

QAnimal qAnimal = QAnimal.animal;
return animalRepository.exists(
        qAnimal.color.in(myList).and(
                qAnimal.name.eq("animal_name")
        )
);
```

I want to mock this queryDsl query using Mockito. In my test file, in the setup method I did:

```
Collection<Book> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add("blue");
myList.add("green");
myList.add("yellow");

QAnimal qAnimal = QAnimal.animal;

when(qAnimal.color.in(myList)).thenReturn((Expressions.asBoolean(false)));
when(qAnimal.name.eq("animal_name")).thenReturn((Expressions.asBoolean(true)));
```

When running the test, I receive the following problem:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

I can't create a JPAQuery object, only use that kind of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you mock `JPAQuery`? At this point you're either testing the internals of Querydsl, or making sure that you wrote what you wrote. Just mock the entire `AnimalRepository` instead. And if you want to test `animalRepository` properly, its best to do so in an integration test that actually executes the query against a database. There is also the possibility to execute the query against mock data using `querydsl-collections`.

If you insist on mocking `JPAQuery` with Mockito stubs however, the easiest way to mock builder API's, like for example `JPAQuery`, is to use `Answers.RETURNS_SELF` as default stub.

For example, use the following to instantiate your `queryMock`:

```java
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SELF) JPAQuery queryMock;
```

Comment: I think  i was misunderstood. I dont want to mock JPAQuery, I want to mock the querydsl code from the first snippet and I get that error

Comment: `qAnimal.color` is static and a field, and Mockito can't really mock statics nor fields, mostly method invocations. However, precisely because of that, there shouldn't be a need to mock `qAnimal.color.in(myList).and(qAnimal.name.eq("animal_name"))` at all, just mock `animalRepository.exists(any())` instead.

Comment: But what if I want different cases to return for the ``animalRepository.exists( .. )`` ? For example, sometimes I want to return false, sometimes to return true? ``animalRepository.exists(any())`` would return always the same thing (true or false)

Comment: `Mockito.when(mock).thenReturn(a, b, c)` takes multiple arguments for return values, for the first, second, third, etc. invocation respectively. So there is no need to use a different parameter to return a different return value from the stub.

Comment: Sounds like a fine workaround, but it might be hard when changing test's input. For the moment, I'll stick with this solution, thanks!

Comment: Mind that `qAnimal.color.in(myList)).thenReturn((Expressions.asBoolean(false))` is by no means what really happens. `qAnimal.color.in(myList)` renders a `animal.color IN (?, ?, ?)` expression, which is itself a boolean expression (in fact it is a predicate). The predicate is constant. Only in SQL it gets eventually evaluated. Even though the outcome might be true or false, the expression it self is never equal to `true` and `false`. A boolean literal is not a predicate.